# Elastic Beanstalk 504 Gateway Errors

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, http-status-code-504

I'm running a simple "hello world" application that runs fine in local development (run with "eb local run"). When I tried deploying to elasticbeanstalk, 20% of requests resolve as 504 Gateway Timeout. The load balancer sends a request to an instance an an instance never seems to receive the request.

How do you diagnose this? The logs simply say the load balancer initiated a request and the instance never seemed to hear about it.

Thank you!

Comment: Security groups for the instance allow connections from the ELB?

Comment: Yes, 80% of requests are fine. Randomly, 20% fail and interestingly they seem to fail more often when coming from curl as opposed to chrome

Comment: Are these requests same for chrome and curl: like same port, same protocl (http, https), paths ...?

Comment: Yes, I've tried https and http, both have the same X% randomly failing.

Comment: You have only 1 instance? Not, e.g. 5, in autoscaling group. Four could be unhealthy but your ELB does not recognize that?

Comment: Only 1. ELB has the option to scale but it hasn't

Comment: What does the cpu/mem utilization look like on the instance?